# Video stream of H.264(avc1.640029) type won't play on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, h.264

**Description**

Here is my demo website and m3u8 source

Demo:
[https://codepen.io/shaoyulan/pen/wvXQoQM](https://codepen.io/shaoyulan/pen/wvXQoQM?editors=1111)

Strem source:
https://stream.huskyking.com/stream/43d1bf49-1769-41f0-ac51-88e6f35d5fc9/index.m3u8

**The problem**

And it's run perfectly at android or windows chrome
But got ERROR (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) at safari
Both iphone and mac

**Reduced test case**

[https://codepen.io/shaoyulan/pen/wvXQoQM](https://codepen.io/shaoyulan/pen/wvXQoQM?editors=1111)

```
<video id="video" controls autoplay muted>
    <source 
       type="application/x-mpegURL"
       src="https://stream.huskyking.com/stream/43d1bf49-1769-41f0-ac51-88e6f35d5fc9/index.m3u8" 
    >
</video>
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. View the page on safari
2. You will see the video is not playable.

**What browser(s) including version(s) does this occur with?**

All Sarari version

**What OS(es) and version(s) does this occur with?**

Safari Both on Iphone and Mac

**What is expected ?**

The stream is expected to playable on safari.

Comment: You need to add your demo / test case to this question, instead of hosting it remotely.

Comment: No Apple stuff here (no Safari/Mac/iOS etc).. but if this was my problem I would check if the M3U8 file is written in a correct format for Apple expectations... Do you have a link of M3U8 that works in iPhone/Mac? I will compare their setup.

Comment: @VC.One Yes I think that has something to do with bad format. So the best tool I can check the format is this one?  [Using Apple's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) Tools](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/using_apple_s_http_live_streaming_hls_tools)   Or what tool would you use?

Comment: @Xiao See if my Answer works correct for you. PS: If still not working, then show me a link to a M3U8 you've seen working inside Safari and I'll check for ideas to fix yours.

Comment: @VC.One Big Thank for your help. I have 2 M3U8 links, one works in Safari and the other doesn't. Here is the links:
1) This link works(Found it on the internet): [link](https://vod02.cdn.web.tv/ps/fp/psfpskkrfpm_,240,360,.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8?st=A5UV1h1aMbWM0ei4JoGWKQ&e=1561248139)
2) This link doesn't work(My link): [link](https://stream.huskyking.com/stream/43d1bf49-1769-41f0-ac51-88e6f35d5fc9/index.m3u8)

Comment: @Xiao Ok finally see if [this m3u8](https://vod02.cdn.web.tv/ps/fp/psfpskkrfpm_,240,360,.mp4.urlset/playlist-f2-v1-a1.m3u8?st=A5UV1h1aMbWM0ei4JoGWKQ&e=1561248139) works? If yes I might have a solution about what changes to put in the text of your own m3u8.

Comment: @VC.One Yes the link you mentioned works in Safari. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: It's difficult to debug without testing... **(1)** I would try removing the `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` line from your m3u8. **(2)** Are you getting any picture (maybe first video frame?) from any testing of the m3u8 or is Safari just always showing a blank screen?

Comment: @VC.One 1) I will try this out later on.  2) Yes, Safari just showing a blank screen. And an error refering MEDIA_ERR_DECODE was emitted by HTMLMediaElement.

Comment: **(1)** See if [this version of your files](https://vc-lut.000webhostapp.com/demos/public/master.m3u8) works in Safari (Mac). **(2)** Usually `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` is from wrong codecs/formats but your codec seems ok (H264 video) and is put inside an okay format (TS files). **(3)** How are you generating the m3u8 file? Is it using FFmpeg or Live555? And what settings? I ask because I see Live555 inside your TS file's bytes. Also when I try to extract the video (to put into MP4 for testing) it gives error about your **SEI** being wrong size (got 263 bytes but actually 264 bytes was expected).

Comment: PS: **SEI** is important metadata along with **PPS** (frame/picture settings) and **SPS** (video sequence settings). MPEG video will not play if any of these 3 items is wrong or is cut-off (without full required bytes for expected size)...

Answer (score 0):

From research... Safari has **built-in M3U8 playback** on `<video>` tag. So at any time, you **don't need** and **cannot use** this **HLS.js** with it (because an important API for playing custom bytes, needed by **HLS.js**, is not available or not supported by the Safari browser).

Try this code in Safari (I cannot test it myself) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="640" height="400" controls>
<source 
type="application/x-mpegURL"
src="https://yioushen-camera.muki001.com/stream/82a4899f-d803-4567-b7c5-221977e14646/index.m3u8" >
</video>

</body>
</html>
```